# WinRT initialization error, hresult_error at memory location

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, wxwidgets, c++-winrt

I am unable to initialize `WinRT/C++` with `wxWidgets`.

`WinRT/C++` works nicely until I add `wxWidgets` support, here is the code:

```
class MyApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

void blemain() {
    winrt::init_apartment();

    std::wcout << "Main thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    myfunc();
}

bool MyApp::OnInit() {
    blemain();
    return true;
}
```

Then executing the `winrt::init_apartment()` function, I get the error: `winrt::hresult_error at memory location`.

Help me.

Comment: What is the error's HRESULT value then?

Comment: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x004FF4A8.
KernelBase.dll[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing , no symbols loadedto KernelBase.dll]

Comment: Do you see the error in Output or do you get the error in your code? If you just see it pass when debugging, but doesn't break your code, it may be a 1st chance exception you don't need to worry, otherwise give us the code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/hresult-error#hresult_errorcode-function

Comment: @xikov, I presume you are building with msvc? And you are using all necessary defines for the project? What happen if you add that initialization to the minimal sample? Try to play with the libraries order and linker settings.

Comment: @simonmouriet, I woul try to catch the exception anyway and see what error is reported. .

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have no any errors in my code, just get that hresult_error. But I found a way to avoid that. As I understand it, the problem is that `winrt::init_apartment();` wants to be called from the `main()` function. But with normal initialization of `wxWidgets`, `wxWidgets` itself creates the `main()` function with the `IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)` macro. And so, my way is using the `IMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(MyApp)` macro.

Comment: Thus, I still have the opportunity to implement the `main()` function, call the initialization of winRT from there `winrt::init_apartment();` and then call `wxEntry(0, 0);` to initialize `wxWidgets`. Of course, if the application was configured as an application with a window, you need to switch to the console application in the linker properties (ProjectProperties -> Linker -> System -> Subsystem).

Comment: This way I managed to bypass the `winRT` initialization error and start the project. `wxWidgets` interface is rendered. An unpleasant feature remains the console that starts with the application and I don’t know what to do with it yet, maybe some other `WinRT` functions of the windowed application are disabled, but this doesn’t bother me for now.

Comment: answer yourself if you're happy or this question will/should be closed

Comment: `winrt::init_apartment()` doesn't care which function it is being called from. Indeed, it doesn't even *know* where it's being called from. The only preconditions it has is that the calling thread hasn't initialized COM previously, or called [RoInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/roapi/nf-roapi-roinitialize) with an incompatible apartment type. If moving `winrt::init_apartment()` appears to be working when calling it earlier, it just means that another COM or WinRT initialization attempt later on fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution (see my comments above).

Perhaps the problem was indeed that `wxWidgets` initialized `COM` and therefore `WinRT` was breaking. At least it works now. I still can't get rid of the console that pops up, but it doesn't bother me too much right now. The topic can be closed. Thanks for answers!

As I understand it, the problem is that `winrt::init_apartment();` wants to be called from the `main()` function. But with normal initialization of `wxWidgets`, `wxWidgets` itself creates the `main()` function with the `IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)` macro. And so, my way is using the `IMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(MyApp)` macro.
Thus, I still have the opportunity to implement the `main()` function, call the initialization of `winRT` from there `winrt::init_apartment();` and then call `wxEntry(0, 0);` to initialize `wxWidgets`. Of course, if the application was configured as an application with a window, you need to switch to the console application in the linker properties (ProjectProperties -> Linker -> System -> Subsystem).
This way I managed to bypass the `winRT` initialization error and start the project. `wxWidgets` interface is rendered. An unpleasant feature remains the console that starts with the application and I don’t know what to do with it yet, maybe some other `WinRT` functions of the windowed application are disabled, but this doesn’t bother me for now.

Comment: Please don't use references to comments as the sole content of your answer. Comments can get deleted at any time, rendering this proposed answer useless. [Answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is not just allowed, it is explicitly encouraged. The answer would still need to be self-contained. As the author you can always [update your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68207990/edit).